# return false and event.preventDefault() are not working

Tags: jquery, json

I have a login form that is suppeosed to submit the name and password to the server and get a json response and change the "login" button to a "log out" button. The code below takes me to the php page that accesses the MySQL database and it stay there as opposes to doing everything in the background. Any explanation why?

this is my jQuery

```
$('#loginbutton').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
    $.post( 'phpcodes.php', $('#loginform').serialize(), function(data) {
         ...do something here
       },
       'json' 
    );
});
```

This is my form:

```
<div id="login" class="menubutton">LOGIN</div>
<div id="loginfields">
  <form action="phpcodes.php" id="loginform" method="post">
  <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='Username' required>
  <input type='text' name='password' placeholder='Password' required>
  <input type='hidden' name='sort' value='1000'>
  <button id='loginbutton' class="menubutton">LOG IN</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

And this is my php:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
if($_POST[sort]==1000)
{
$_POST[username] = filter_var($_POST[username], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$_POST[password] = filter_var($_POST[password], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM users where name ='$_POST[username]' and password='$_POST[password]'"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$listings_results[] = array(
    'user'=>$row[name],
                        );
$_SESSION[user]=$row[name];
}
mysql_close($connection);
$results[results] = $listings_results;
// send the encoded results;
$json = @json_encode($results);
echo $json;
}
?>
```

the answer I get on the php page is correct but it should be transmitted in the background to my original page and displayed in the div with the id "login".

Comment: Most likely you ran the event binding code too soon. Is this the first time you've used jQuery?

Comment: I edited the code and added event.preventDefault(); this was the original code I was trying which worked many times befor for me but now I am stuck and cannot find the error...

Comment: Oh yes and I am a novice in jquery to answer your other question.

Comment: I edited the code and removed type='submit' from the form, but it still takes me to the php page

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){...})`

Comment: but how is the form being submitted by a button that's not type="submit"?

Comment: @CupawnTae that's the default behavior. If you're going to use form tags, you should be using the form submit event.

Comment: well blow me down, I thought type="button" was default, well that should solve it

Comment: @KevinB I added that and now after clicking the submit button I am stuck on my original page.

Comment: @Sandor i thought that was what you wanted. That's kinda what happens when you prevent the submit and use ajax instead.

Comment: @KevinB - Well, in place of "...do something" I put a simple code

    document.getElementById("login") = "LOGOUT";

just to see if the code works, but the div is not updating so I don't believe anything is happening in the background.

Comment: @KevinB now maybe we're back to not having registered the handler at the right time?

Comment: Make sure your jQuery code is wrapped in a ready event handler as in KevinB's comment above, or put it at the end of your document, if you haven't already done one of these.

Comment: well, that's not how you update a div's html. you forgot the .innerHTML part.

Comment: Riiiiight... Its all working now fine, thank you for all the comments, answers and good input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't want `type="submit"` on the button because you don't want the browser to submit the form. If you change it to `type="button"`, then it won't submit the form, and you won't leave the current page.

Next, remove the return false from your handler, and you should have what you want.

You can add `onsubmit="return false"` to the form to stop the submit-on-enter, or you could use something other than a form tag to contain the inputs. However, if you are not using a form tag, you will have to explicitly select the input you want to serialize in your click handler instead of just selecting the form element as in your original code.

Comment: except, that the form will submit when you press enter on an input. (but that will happen with his current code too)

Comment: removed type="submit" and removed return false - still no improvement

Comment: That's a different problem - the GET is not being caused by the event. You sure you're not using JSONP rather than JSON? JSONP is always a GET. Or could there be a server-side redirect?

Comment: @KevinB good point, I added ideas to foil the submit-on-enter

Comment: @Sandor you edited your comment above while I was replying, so I'm confused. Are you saying that with no type="submit" on the button, it is still changing page when you click it? That doesn't make sense. If you put an alert("yo") in the handler, does it fire?

Comment: It's JSON. I just mixed up  type="submit" with method = "post" there for a second. When I was fiddeleing with the code I removed method = "post" and that's when I was getting the GET method.

Comment: @CupawnTae - yes, after removing the type="submit" it still takes me to the phpcodes.php site and I stay there, which makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: @Sandor, KevinB pointed out my error - type="button" is not default, you need to add it explicitly and *then* it won't submit the form - I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You are returning false before executing the ajax request, which is definitely going to be a problem. Also, you are going to want to give your click-handler an argument, like 'e', so you can actually call preventDefault() on the click event.

Comment: I edited the code and added event.preventDefault(); this was the original code I was trying which worked many times befor for me but now I am stuck and cannot find the error...